# How to create observables of click () events for every row in an Angular Material table and respond to all of them?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

> I was able to do it with an HTML button also with an Angular Material
> button But in an Angular Material table I only manage to do it in the
> first row First use fromEvent creating observables that emit event
> clicks when not getting the desired result then try it with Renderer2
> It is not possible for me to find the way to be able to subscribe to
> each clik () event that is emitted in the table either using merge
> with @ViewChildren ()  I could not do it either inside a table of angular material DOM events in Anbular Material Table

```js
//ts
import { Renderer2,AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// modal de una tabla
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material',
  templateUrl: './material.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material.component.scss']
})
export class MaterialComponent implements AfterViewInit , OnInit, OnDestroy{
  buttonsClik!:() => void;
  documentClick!: () => void;

 @ViewChild('testBtn', { static: true }) testBtn!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 event$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.testBtn.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
   map(() => new Date().toString()),
   tap(console.log)
 )
 
 @ViewChild('pdfExterno',{ read: ElementRef }) pdfExterno!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 @ViewChild('docx',{ read: ElementRef }) docx!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 pdfExterno$=defer(() => fromEvent(this.pdfExterno.nativeElement, 'click')).pipe(
   map(() => new Date().toString()),
   tap(console.log)
  )
  @ViewChild('pdf',{ read: ElementRef }) pdf!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
 @ViewChild('mostrar',{ read: ElementRef }) mostrar!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

 displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol','descargaPdfDoc'];
 dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
//another way I try with Renderer2 I try to catch not only the click () events of //the first row
 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
 this.buttonsClik();
 this.documentClick();
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.event$.subscribe();
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.pdfExterno$.subscribe()
   this.render();
   console.log(this.pdf);
   console.log(this.docx);
   console.log(this.mostrar);
    /* I can not with

  
   <div>
        <button  id="pdf"   #pdf (click)="(pdf.id) ;descargarPDF(row)" >PDF</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button   id="docx" #docx (click)="(docx.id);descargarDocx(row)" >DOCX </button>
      </div>
    </div>
*/
   merge(
fromEvent(this.pdf.nativeElement, 'click'),
fromEvent(this.docx.nativeElement, 'click'),

).subscribe((event: Event | null)=> {
  console.log('desde Merge',event?.target);
});

  /* I can not with
   docx$!: Observable<any>;
   this.docx$=fromEvent(this.docx.nativeElement, 'click')
.pipe(

  map(()=>new Date().toString()),
  tap(console.log)
  )
  this.docx$.subscribe(e=>console.log('docx',e))
  */
 }
 render(){
  this.documentClick = this.renderer.
  listen('document', 'click', (event:MouseEvent) =>{

    console.log('Desde render docx',event)
   } )

 this.buttonsClik= this.renderer.
  listen(this.docx.nativeElement, 'click', (event:MouseEvent) =>{

    console.log('Desde render docx',event)
   } )


  this.renderer.listen(this.pdf.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
    console.log('Desde render pdf',event)
  })
  this.renderer.listen(this.mostrar.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
    console.log('Desde Render mostrar',event)
  })
}
  onDocumentClick(e: any): boolean | void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
descargarPDF(row:any){
  console.log('pdf',row)
}

descargarDocx(row:any){
  console.log('docx',row)

  }

  onRowClicked(row:any): void{
    console.log('mat-row',row)
  }

  descargarPDFFueraDeMatTable(){
    console.log('funciona')
  }

}
// html
<h1>Fuera de la Tabla sin problemas</h1>
<section>
  <div>
    <button #testBtn>Click me</button>
  </div>
  <div>

</div>
</section>
<button mat-raised-button
 (click)="descargarPDFFueraDeMatTable()"
 #pdfExterno>PDF</button>
<h1>Dentro de la tabla solo puede vincular a un Observable para la 1 fila</h1>
<div class="container text-center">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #mytable class="mat-elevation-z8">


    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>
      <!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="descargaPdfDoc">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Descarga</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="u-text-align-center" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <button  id="pdf"   #pdf (click)="(pdf.id) ;descargarPDF(row)" >PDF</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button   id="docx" #docx (click)="(docx.id);descargarDocx(row)" >DOCX </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" #mostrar (click)="onRowClicked(row);$event.stopPropagation()">
</tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: ViewChild only get the "first" element. You should use ViewChildren. BTW, why not simply use in row the event click? `<tr mat-row *matRowDef (click)="whatever(...)">`

Comment: Thanks for answering what you say is true but My problem is that it is a table of angular material I also tried the way you say but I could not do it I only wrote code in some of the ways that I tried
It seems to me that the entire table should be accessed first with @ViewChild and then refer to its elements but I know how to do it

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. Your `onRowClicked` will probably trigger every time you click a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your intent, but it seems you are doing something much more complicated than what the title of your question suggests. Use of `@ViewChild` and `Renderer2` are not necessary to:

> "*create observables of click events for every row in an Angular Material table and respond to all of them*"

To create a stream of Events on click, you can simply push events through a [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects):

```js
private rowClick$ = new Subject<Event>();

public onRowClick(event: Event) {
  this.rowClick$.next(event);
}
```

Instead of pushing the `Event`, you could push the `PeriodicElement` data if you wanted to:

```js
private rowClick$ = new Subject<PeriodicElement>();

public onRowClick(data: PeriodicElement) {
  this.rowClick$.next(data);
}
```

---

It sort of looks like you are trying to create a stream of "render jobs".  If that's the case, you could do something like this:

```js
  private renderJob$ = new Subject<RenderJob>();

  descargarPDF(row: PeriodicElement) {
    this.renderJob$.next({ type: 'pdf', data: row });
  }

  descargarDocx(row: PeriodicElement) {
    this.renderJob$.next({ type: 'docx', data: row });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderJob$.subscribe(
      ({ type, data }) => console.log(`[render job received] type: ${type}`, data)
    );
  }
```

Here are a couple Stackblitz links you can play with:

- [Your Original Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70476865-original?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&devtoolsheight=50)
- [Proposed Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70476865-solution?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&devtoolsheight=50)

Comment: Thanks simple and clean solution thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecesary, but if you has,e.g. a button in a td

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <button #bt>{{element.weight}}</button>
</td>
```

You can use, after give value to the dataSource

```
@ViewChildren('bt') bts:QueryList<ElementRef>

//After give value to dataSource
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

//enclosed in a setTimeout
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.bts.forEach(x=>{
    fromEvent(x.nativeElement,'click').subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
  })
})
```

See that you need "enclosed" in a setTimeout to give time to Angular to draw the table

Comment: the problem is that I have three clik () events that can be seen in the code Greetings

Comment: Your solution does not work for me. Test your solution in the code that you publish and it does not even respond to a row of angular material table the code that I publish with render2 and with @viewChild at least it responds to the first row